# Composer install Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer on my Website. [The Composer documentations](https://getcomposer.org/download/) suggests running this command:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`
```

but when I do, I get an error:

> Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r

I use PHP Version 7.0

What's going on here?

Comment: welcome to SO.  if you are copy/pasting text make sure it is not pasting Smartquotes

Comment: I checked this, that was not the problem.

Comment: `php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55d6ead61b29c7bdee5cccfb50076874187bd9f21f65d8991d46ec5cc90518f447387fb9f76ebae1fbbacf329e583e30') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"` worked for me on php 5.4.45 perhaps its a 7.0 thing

Comment: I've edited your question fairly aggressively. If you feel I've gone too far, please feel free to [edit] further or even roll it back.

Comment: I used `php5-cli` instead of `php`, which worked.

Answer (score 9):

I suspect `php` in your case is referring to PHP's CGI-SAPI binary instead of the CLI that it should be. [As documented in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php), the CGI-SAPI does not include the `-r` option:

> Note:
>   -r is available in the CLI SAPI, but not in the CGI SAPI.

You can confirm that this is the case by checking "`php`'s" version with the `-v` flag.

Proper setup should show that `php` is a CLI interupter:

```
C:\Users\HPierce>php -v
PHP 7.0.8 (cli) (built: Jun 21 2016 15:27:20) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Improper setup might show that it is the CGI SAPI:

```
C:\Users\HPierce>php-cgi -v
PHP 7.0.8 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jun 21 2016 15:27:08)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

You can resolve this by referencing the CLI binary with an absolute path instead of the `php` shortcut that utilizies your OS's `$PATH` environment variable:

```
C:\php\php.exe -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and used curl and it worked:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /usr/bin/php7.1-cli
```

Additionally, to do specific commands to install a package, I needed to specify the php version Composer was installed on, and write "composer.phar" instead of only composer:

```
php7.1-cli composer.phar require exampleAppDirectory/exampleAppName
```