# Problems with composer install Error in argument 1, char 2 on server

Tags: php, server, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer on my server.

But I've run into a problem.

When I run this command:

`php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`

I get this error message:

> Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r

I've read it because of my PHP interpreter.

when I type: `php -v`, I  get:

> PHP 8.1.9 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Aug 10 2022 17:15:13) Copyright (c) The
> PHP Group Zend Engine v4.1.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

How do I change cgi-fcgi to cli?

Or is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Hi - have you had a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491697/composer-install-error-in-argument-1-char-2-option-not-found-r

Comment: Hi! thanks for replying, yes i have indeed but that didnt help for me im downloading it on a hosting server. So i dont think i can referencing the CLI binary with an absolute path.

Comment: Ok! Have you tried typing "php" and then hit the tab button 2 times? Then the terminal will show you available commands starting with "php".

Comment: php       php43     php44pl   php53     php56     php70     php71es   php73     php80     phpdbg70  phpdbg73  phpdbg81  
php3      php43pl   php5      php53es   php56es   php70es   php72     php73es   php81     phpdbg71  phpdbg74  
php4      php44     php52     php55     php5pl    php71     php72es   php74     phpdbg56  phpdbg72  phpdbg80  doesnt seem like php to me, whats up with my php hahah

Comment: I would try with php81. If that not helps you can install php-cli by yourself. It seems like you are using Alpine linux. In that case this command will install php-cli for you `apk update && apk add php-cli`

Comment: thanks again, im running this system of php Linux localhost 3.10.0-1160.71.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP when i type : "apk update && apk add php-cli" i get : apk update && apk add php-cli
-bash: apk: command not found, im also using php version 8.1.9

Comment: Don't run composer on that server. Instead create the package where you can control all the build tools and then just deploy the package on the server. You can hint the platform version to directly build the target package on a development host.